# Error in importing project to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-storm

I'm new in java and storm

i imported a project in eclipse with the needed  library and i got errors in some code

The code of the project i imported here

https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter .

and i run pom.xml using Maven  .. Build Successfully .

I'm using eclipse Kelper Jee Release .

the photo i upload it show more about my problem .

[image: errors]

`[image: warning]

what about warning i have . it's suppose for project ... work well ? am i ignore it or no ?

Comment: Now if only we could see the whole screen and the error message in full...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... must override a super class ... is because the project's Java compiler compliance level is 1.5 but it needs 1.6. Java 1.5 does not allow @Override annotations on methods implementing interface methods. Try right click on project -> Properties -> Java Compiler set compliance level 1.6 or 1.7

Comment: I'm new in java  how do you know that the project uses J2se 1.6 ? and what's different between  j2se and jre and jdk ?

Comment: ok i have  jdk 1.6 and jre 1.6 and java 6 . Now how can i make the compiler 1.6 ?

Comment: right click on project -> properties -> java build path -> check under libraries tab

Comment: what about warning i have . it's suppose for project ... work well ? am i ignore it or no ?

Comment: I would try to fix eg List list -> List<Object> list.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is problem in **version of jars** that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

`Go To Window -->Preference` Check Java Compilation level,Check your `java Build path JRE included` correctly or not `JRE version is Low` Find `1.6 instead of 1.5`